# WinForms Export UserControl derived class, but not in-between classes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DLL that I'm making for Windows Forms applications.  The layout looks a little something like this

```
public class A : UserControl 
{ 
   protected C c;
}

public class B : A { }

public class C { }
```

**I want the DLL to *only* export `class B`, but it will not compile if I remove the public qualifier from A or C.  Is there a way to do this?**

Error from removing public from A:

```
Error   CS0060  Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'A' is less accessible than class 'B'
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @itsme86 mostly just hiding stuff that our customers don't need to know about to simplify importing it into their project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN - Restrictions on Using Accessibility Levels (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx03xt0t.aspx):

> When you specify a type in a declaration, check whether the accessibility level of the type is dependent on the accessibility level of a member or of another type. For example, the direct base class must be at least as accessible as the derived class.

Usually, in order to hide "stuff" from others, what you do, is provide a public interface and hide all the sub-classes. You can let your client create the concrete classes with a public factory which you will provide as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.  If `B` inherits `A`, you simply cannot expose `B` without exposing `A`.